# SQL Select ID no duplicate rows with same ID

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I have a table called MOVIES:

```
id|movie
1 |Batman
1 |Batman
2 |Superman
3 |Spiderman
4 |Ironman
4 |Ironman
```

I want an output like this:

```
1 |Batman
2 |Superman
3 |Spiderman
4 |Ironman
```

How can i accomplish this ?

(This is my current code, which doesnt work)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, movie
FROM MOVIES
GROUP By ID, movie
```

Comment: *which doesnt work*...why?, what's the problem?. Anyway, the `GROUP BY` isn't needed at all

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`. `select distinct Id, Movie from Movies;`

Comment: Please provide which dbms you are using and provide what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: What are the types of columns ? Maybe the difference comes from spaces in a CHAR or VARCHAR2 column ? In this case try with the function TRIM() : `SELECT DISTINCT ID, TRIM(movie) FROM MOVIES`.

Comment: Using `group by` helped me so much in my situation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use either **DISTINCT or GROUP BY**:

**DISTINCT** - will eliminate duplicates from defined set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, movie
FROM MOVIES
```

**GROUP BY** - is grouping by selected columns, additionally it allows for using aggregate functions, but in simplest form you can use it in the same way as DISTINCT:

```
SELECT ID, movie
FROM MOVIES
GROUP By ID, movie
```

As @Lamak noticed there is nothing wrong in using both in this case, it is just unnecessary.

Comment: I mean, this is true, op should use just one, but there's no actual problem in using `SELECT DISTINCT somecolumns GROUP BY somecolumns`

Comment: Agreed, but op didn't really specified what kind problem is facing.